# Does C# System.String Instances Really End Up on the Heap?

Tags: c#, stack, .net-assembly, heap-memory, cil

Let's consider some very simple C# code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 5;
            string s = "ABC";
            bool b = false;
        }
```

Jeffrey Richter's "*CLR via C#*" (Chapter 14) states that "*The String type is derived immediately from Object, making it a reference type, and therefore, String objects (its array of characters) always live in the heap, never on a thread's stack*".

Also referring to strings, on an example in the book quite similar to the one above: "*The newobj IL instruction constructs a new instance of an object. However, no newobj instruction appears in the IL code example. Instead, you see the special ldstr (load string) IL instruction, which constructs a String object by using a literal string obtained from metadata. This shows you that the common language runtime (CLR) does, in fact, have a special way of constructing literal String objects.*"

Looking at the IL code, this is clearly the case (only relevant part shown):

```
[...]
    .locals init (
        [0] int32,
        [1] string,
        [2] bool
    )
    // (no C# code)
    IL_0000: nop
    // int num = 5;
    IL_0001: ldc.i4.5
    IL_0002: stloc.0
    // string text = "ABC";
    IL_0003: ldstr "ABC"
    IL_0008: stloc.1
    // bool flag = false;
[...]
```

The `ldstr` IL instruction [ensures that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldstr?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) "*an object reference to a string is pushed onto the stack*". Which makes sense - the instance of the string stays on the heap, and the reference to this object (its address) is stored  by the variable on the stack.

Now let's set a breakpoint on the line following variable `text` being declared, start debugging in Visual Studio and then switch to the Disassembly view. Relevant code follows (the full disassembled code is [here](https://gist.github.com/luckerby/5f171e18e1cdeacb3558db14d08ec827)):

```
017B0483  nop  
            int i = 5;
017B0484  mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],5  
            string s = "ABC";
017B048B  mov         eax,dword ptr ds:[429231Ch]  
017B0491  mov         dword ptr [ebp-44h],eax  
            bool b = false;
017B0494  xor         edx,edx  
017B0496  mov         dword ptr [ebp-48h],edx  
        }
```

Looking specifically at the 2 assembly instructions handling the C# `string` line, the first one moves the content of the virtual memory at `429231C` to the `eax` register, and the second stores the respective content on the stack, where the `s` variable lives.

Let's use WinDbg (x86, since the C# code is using the VS' default 32-bit target platform) to look at that specific address, by attaching to the process being debugged by VS, in a non-invasive mode. The content of `429231C` above should be a reference to the memory space where the string actually lives. Let's check:

[image]

The second command does yield a `41`, `42` and `43` in hex, which do represent `A`, `B` and `C` in ASCII; <strike>however the order is not all right and might just be a coincidence. **(1) It doesn't look as the assembly code for the string line does things right.**</strike>

If we use VMMap to look at that address:
[image]

The original address `429231C` looks to be within the managed heap. But then **(2) why would the content of an address on the heap be brought in as the reference contained within a stack variable, as the assembly code previously looked to indicate ?**

The <strike>2</strike> question<strike>s</strike> I'm asking are <strike>(1) and</strike> (2). Despite the fact that everything makes sense to me right up to analyzing the IL code, things go downhill fast once I look at the disassembled code for that IL. I tend to think that I'm rather messing something up in my logic (most likely) or I'm hitting some sort of bug in the VS debugger (less likely).

**Later Update**: As very well pointed out by @madreflection and @Jester, endianness tripped me. The hex representation checks out all right. Only question **(2)** now remains.

**Later Update 2**: The comments have been quite insightful, and I think @madreflection puts it best - there's an additional level of indirection - and the reasons for doing this (stated in the comments) start to make sense to me now. A quick diagram is below. I've also checked that both addresses do indeed belong to the managed heap with VMMap.

[image]

**Later Update 3**: Corrected previous diagram.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194568/discussion-on-question-by-mihai-albert-does-c-system-string-instances-really-en).