# Why C# using same memory address in this case?

Tags: c#, .net-core

When I executing this code

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
//scope 1 
            {
                string x = "shark";
                string y = x.Substring(0);
                unsafe
                {
                    fixed (char* c = y)
                    {
                        c[4] = 'p';
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(x);
            }
//scope 2
            {
                string x = "shark";
//Why output in this line "sharp" and not "shark" ?
                Console.WriteLine(x);
            }
        }
}
```

the output is:

```
sharp
sharp
```

When I separate this 2 scopes in methods like this:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            func1();
            func2();
        }
        private static void func2()
        {
            {
                string x = "shark";
                Console.WriteLine(x);
            }
        }

        private static void func1()
        {
            {
                string x = "shark";
                string y = x.Substring(0);
                unsafe
                {
                    fixed (char* c = y)
                    {
                        c[4] = 'p';
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(x);
            }
        }
    }
```

the output is:

```
sharp
shark
```

**Edited**

I also try this way:

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            {
                string x = "shark";
                string y = x.Substring(0);
                unsafe
                {
                    fixed (char* c = y)
                    {
                        c[4] = 'p';
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(x);
            }
            void Test(){
                {
                    string x = "shark";
                    Console.WriteLine(x);
                }
            }
            Test();
        }
}
```

and the output is:

```
 sharp
 shark
```

**Environment which I used is MacOS and .net core 2.2 (Rider) **

I expect to have same output in all cases, but the output is different. As we know interning is that all strings you hardcoded are put into assembly and reused globally in the whole application to reuse same memory space. But in case of this code we see that

*hardcoded strings reused only in function scope and not in global scope*.

**Is this a .NET Core bug or this have explanation ?**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Probably something to do with strings being interned, and `x.Substring(0)` giving you the exact same string.

Comment: Adding to that, strings are immutable, so you're violating a long-established covenant that you don't modify string memory directly. Use a `StringBuilder` if you need to modify strings that way.

Comment: Why would it be a 'bug' when you use `unsafe` to access implementation defined details?  What you are internal optimizations of the string class, but nothing is breaking any contracts.

Comment: _"I expect to ..."_ Try to find a clause in the C# or .NET specifications for that expectation.

Comment: `.NET Core bug` It definitely isn't a bug. You are doing something explicitly marked `unsafe`. And then experienced what is, to you, unexpected behaviour since interning (which is an implementation detail) is not acting the exact way you expect. Undefined behaviour is undefined - nothing in the spec says the code can't act the way it is acting. So definitely not a bug. It is _odd_ at best - but not a bug.

Comment: I was surprised by this question, i have tested this every way i can, i cant reproduce your resutls. its always the first results. however i am using framework, not core

Comment: @TheGeneral I get this result on MacOS with .NET Core 2.2

Comment: @hovjan: You're separating scopes, but you've modified string contents that exist outside that scope. String literals are like global variables. For a single literal value, there's one instance and the compiler reuses it. Because strings are immutable, it can *safely* do that. Until you introduce an *unsafe* context that violates those expectations. You assigned `x` in different scopes to the same global variable and modified the global variable, affecting any other scope that would use that global variable.

Comment: @hovjan: I'd love to dig into that because I haven't seen the behavior myself yet and  I love this in-depth stuff. However, I think you're missing the point here, and that is that you shouldn't be modifying the string. End of story.

Comment: @hovjan The fundamental question you are asking here is 'why, when I do this `unsafe` thing is it not acting the way I expect it to?'. And the answer, as unexciting is it is, is this - **because it never promised to**. The spec doesn't say that string interning has to occur a specific way. So, while what you have found is _interesting_ - that is **all** it is. It definitely, 100%, is not a bug. A bug, by definition, means there must be some specification about how it is **supposed** to behave. The takeaway here is simple - **stop using `unsafe`** to do silly things.

Comment: @mjwills I just use unsafe to understand does CLR store all hardcoded string with the same hash in same memory.

Comment: The answer is - no. It is not **required** to do that. It might, or it might not. It is, literally, undefined. In practical terms, it makes no difference since normal code (without `unsafe` manipulation like yours) **will work the same regardless**.

Comment: @mjwills  Thanks a lot. **NO** This is the answer of my question.

Comment: String unsafe manipulation is illegal, so any outcome is justifiable, including your app breaking after it was working once.
https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/14208#issuecomment-332650504

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compilation going function by function thats why in first case if you put string in one scope compiler checking strings one time and putting in `Intern Pool` only one string and when you change in memory it's changed for all hardcoded strings.

In second case when I put strings in different functions compiler adding string to `Intern Pool` for only first function and when we changing string with unsafe code its applying changes to that string after compiler going to second method and trying to find the string `shark` but in `Interned Pool` compiler could not find that kind of string (because we already change it to `sharp`), thats why it add new string and the output become different.

Answer (score 7):

**Note the question has changed since i wrote this**

If you look at the [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/8124961f027d9ac9.html).

```
if( startIndex == 0 && length == this.Length) {
   return this;
}
```

So when you use `Substring(0)` you get a *reference* to the original, then *mutating* it with `unsafe`

In the second example `Substring(1)` is allocating a `string`.

---

More in depth analysis.

```
string x = "shark";
string y = x.Substring(0);
// x reference and y reference are pointing to the same place

// then you mutate the one memory
c[4] = 'p';

// second scope
string x = "shark";
string y = x.Substring(1);
// x reference and y reference are differnt

// you are mutating y
c[0] = 'p';
```

**Edit**

The `string` is *interened*, and the compiler thinks any *literal* of `"shark"` is the same (via a hash). This is why the second part even with different variables produced the mutated result

> String interning refers to having a single copy of each unique string
>   in an string intern pool, which is via a hash table in the.NET common
>   language runtime (CLR). Where the key is a hash of the string and the
>   value is a reference to the actual String object

Debugging the second part (without or without scope and different variables)

[image]

**Edit 2**

Scope doesn't matter for me or framework or core, it always produced the same result (the first), it could well be an implementation detail, and losely defined nature of internment in the specs

Comment: I understand how works `Substring(0)` memory allocation, i need to understand why `string x` declaration in second scope working wrong

Comment: @hovjan Because you get assigned a different string when you do `.Substring(1)`

Comment: @John Can you explain more detailed when I assigned new string to `y` why my second `x` output are equal to first `x` output as you see in my output:  **first x -> sharp**
sharp
**second x -> sharp**
parp

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56468304/does-c-sharp-system-string-instances-really-end-up-on-the-heap). The OP discovered that when you load a string literal, it goes to a lookup table to find the address of the string. When you modified the string the first time, you modified the string in the lookup table, so every *literal* with the same contents was modified because it's the same instance everywhere it's used.

Comment: @madreflection You're correct. That's exactly the behaviour [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.intern?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) talk about.

Comment: @madreflection when i actually tested this, scope didn't matter in Framework 4.7.2. It was always the first result

Comment: @madreflection yeah i must admit i had to edit this multiple times. as i started exploring it. Also to just tested in core. and same results. Scope doesn't even matter.

Answer (score 3):

As has already been pointed out, this is happening because you are changing the interned string itself, which will change the string for everything that uses that interned string.

It's interesting to note that you *do* see this changing if you separate out the two methods like so:

```
using System;

namespace CoreApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string x = "shark";
            Console.WriteLine("Main: " + x);

            func2(); // If you comment this out, then the  below call to func2() outputs "shark" instead of "sharp"
            func1();
            Console.WriteLine("Main: " + x);

            func2();
        }

        static void func1()
        {
            string x = "shark";
            string y = x.Substring(0);

            unsafe
            {
                fixed (char* c = y)
                {
                    c[4] = 'p';
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("func1(): " + x);
        }

        static void func2()
        {
            string x = "shark";
            Console.WriteLine("func2(): " + x);
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the code above is:

```
Main: shark
func2(): shark
func1(): sharp
Main: sharp
func2(): sharp
```

Interestingly, if you comment out the first call to func2(), the output is:

```
Main: shark
func1(): sharp
Main: sharp
func2(): shark
```

The reason for the difference is a little harder to explain. I think one would have to look at the actual IL generated to see if anything is being cached.

Note that you can change an interned string *without* using unsafe code, like so:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CoreApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string test  = "ABCDEF"; // Strings are immutable, right?
            char[]       chars = new StringToChar { str = test }.chr;
            chars[0] = 'X';

            // On an x32 release or debug build or on an x64 debug build, 
            // the following prints "XBCDEF".
            // On an x64 release build, it prints "ABXDEF".
            // In both cases, we have changed the contents of 'test' without using
            // any 'unsafe' code...

            Console.WriteLine(test);

            // The following line is even more disturbing, since the constant
            // string "ABCDEF" has been mutated too (because the interned 'constant' string was mutated).

            Console.WriteLine("ABCDEF");
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct StringToChar
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)] public string str;
        [FieldOffset(0)] public char[] chr;
    }
}
```

This is, of course, a little surprising, but it's not a bug.

Comment: Still not answering the question... Why does string interning happen in different scopes but not in different methods? And I'm also confused about this, since, in theory, according to the documentation, it should happen at application level.

Comment: @StefanBalan String interning *is* happening in different methods, as my code above demonstrates (a call to `func1()` changes the output of  `func2()`. However there is some additional complexity introduced by the JIT compiler, which is likely to be generating code which caches some data and makes the results harder to interpret.

Comment: Yeah this is strange, im starting to think this is implementation as op is on mac

Comment: @MatthewWatson thanks for your answer but in **MacOS** the result different as I show in screenshots attached to my question. And as you see I open IL View to check does something cached, but as I see nothing was cached.

Comment: @hovjan Actually, I see the same results on Windows as you're getting,

Comment: @hovjan: this is cached on a lower level than IL code, it's actually the ldstr opcode that looks up the interned strings table https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldstr?view=netframework-4.8 - when you split it into separate method it actually looks for the second time, and it uses the cached value if its the same method for some reason. But you can check that if you change "shark" to "sharp" and the ldstr "sharp" it will return pointer to same string

Answer (score 1):

Learn about string interning https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.intern?view=netframework-4.8

Read string from console input or compose it at runtime rather than compile time if you don't want to have an interned reference. Also strings should always stay immutable, otherwise it may cause problems not only with interned strings but also with thread-safety. Do not ever touch strings that has `.IsInterned` flag set

Comment: Did you mean that if I use two scopes C# using String.Intern ?? I don't think so

Comment: @hovjan No, it simply means that C# interns strings.

Comment: @John C# Interns the strings even the string in different scopes ?

Comment: What does the scope matter?

Comment: You can't define 2 variables with the same name in one scope, thats why I add second scope and declare new variable with the same name `x` but CLR are getting value from another scope

Comment: @John: when you execute it in a single scope, the string will be loaded once and compared with interned ones. When you split it into two methods, the string will be loaded once again, but this time will not use interned instance because it got altered and doesn't match anymore

Comment: @hovjan: it's not about variable names at all, you can use any variable names you'd like. The point of interning is that all strings you hardcoded are put into assembly and reused globally in the whole application to reuse same memory space. Scope doesn't matter. Just read your strings from console input

Comment: @Adassko in that case why I getting different result in next example ? (Please take a look to image attached in question)

Comment: @madreflection can you explain the difference of this two codes ?